# How to get list of all Route URL strings in play framework?

Tags: scala, playframework

I have many controllers in my **play 2.4.x** application.

I want to get a list of `all route URLs` pointing their respective controllers. I know how to get the URL from the current request. But I need a list of all the URLs available inside a play application.I want to `generate this list dynamically because URLs can be changed/added/deleted in future`.

*So,is there some way I can generate this URL list dynamically ? Or do I have the obligation to store all the URLs statically somewhere in cache or dictionary ?*

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaRouting#Reverse-routing Play generates a routes package for each controller package. You could try to use reflection somehow to iterate over these packages and containing ReverseRoutes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I obtained the desired list by using the `documentation` method provided by **Router trait**. The documentation method returns `Seq[(String, String, String)]` .Here each tuple has the format:

> ( {http-method} , {url} , {controller method} )

The **Router trait** is extended by all the autogenerated `Routes.scala` classes. Scala-compiler generated a separate `Routes.scala` for each `routes` file in the application. These auto-generated `Routes.scala` files implement all the methods of **Router trait** including the documentation method that we discussed above.

So,to get list of all URLs, I simply had to `inject the Router trait` and then access the `documentation method`:

```
import play.api.routing.Router

class MyClass @Inject()(router: Router) {
 def getAllURLs:Seq[String] = router.documentation.map(k => k._2)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Update for Play 2.7, Scala:

`class MyController @Inject()(routesProvider: Provider[play.api.routing.Router]) {
      lazy val routes: Seq[(String, String, String)] = routesProvider.get.documentation
 }`

[from discussion for play 2.6](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/8TatPRJ972U)

Comment: ☝️This is the correct answer for Play 2.6+.  
The previous answer will result in a cyclic dependency error.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the accepted answer: Note that if you're working in a Controller and you try to inject the Router, you'll get a Circular Dependency error (because the Router depends on your Controller). You can fix this by doing the following:

```
private final Provider<Router> routerProvider;
@Inject
public MainController(Provider<Router> routerProvider) {
    this.routerProvider = routerProvider;
}
```

And then

```
// later in execution
Router router = routerProvider.get();

if (!router.documentation().isEmpty()) {
  html.append("<ul>");

  router.documentation().forEach(doc ->
      html.append("<li>")
          .append("<b>Method</b>: ")
          .append(doc.getHttpMethod())
          .append("  <b>Path</b>: ")
          .append(doc.getPathPattern())
          .append("  <b>Controller</b>: ")
          .append(doc.getControllerMethodInvocation())
          .append("</li>"));

  html.append("</ul>");
}
```